# Make ESLint apply rules to only certain file name patterns

Tags: eslint

Is it possible to configure ESLint in a way that it only applies rules to files that names are matching certain pattern? I know it's possible to have separate rule sheets in directories, but in case the structure is following:

```
app
|
|- module1
|     |- module1.js
|     |- module1.spec.js
|
|- module2
|     |- module2.js
|     |- module2.spec.js
```

And I want a project-wide rules that would only apply to the *.spec.js files.
I'd expect to have a setting like

```
"include-pattern": "*.spec.js"
```

in the .eslintrc or any other, simlilar way to specify which filenames should be considered for specific rules.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

Yes, now it's possible. In your example it could look like

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "quotes": [2, "double"]
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["app/module1/*.js"],
      "excludedFiles": "*.spec.js",
      "rules": {
        "quotes": [2, "single"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can read more at [eslint doc page](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#example-configuration).

**Old answer:**

Currently this is not supported. But for `2.0.0` version we are actively working on this feature.

To track progress: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/3611

Comment: This applies ALL rules to specified files - is there a way to apply just a single rule to a set of files?

Answer (score 9):

Temporary workaround is to use `.eslintignore` file with something like this inside:

`*.js
!*.spec.js`

Answer (score 0):

Just make a "lint" script in your package.json and append any pattern you want:

```
"lint": "npx eslint src/**/*.ts test/**/*.ts",
```

Then `npm run lint`.

I also make a bash alias `alias n='npm run'`, so `n lint` works for me..